# Rewrite nginx с картинки на страницу

Tags: nginx, mod_rewrite

Как прописать правило в nginx так что бы при запросе картинки

> http://site.ru/ping/images/324565789/i.png

перенаправлялось на адрес

> http://site.ru/ping/324565789/

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/ping/images/(\d+)/\w+\.(png|jpeg|gif)$ /ping/$1/ redirect;
}
```

Вариант для .htaccess на всякий случай:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ping/images/(\d+)/\w+.(png|jpeg|gif)$ ping/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: в nginx'овом `rewrite` поправьте `%` на `$`  ( `$1` )

Answer (score 0):

Если вы так реализуете счётчик, и `/ping/324565789/` это тоже в свою очередь скрипт типа `/ping.php?id=324565789` который возвращает картинку, то так ([подробнее про `rewrite`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)):

```
rewrite ^/ping/images/(\d+)/i\.png$ /ping/$1/ last;
```

Либо можно так, если `/ping/12345/` больше не переписывается и где-то прямо лежат физические файлы ([подробнее про `alias`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias)):

```
location ~ ^/ping/images/(\d+)/i.png$ {
    alias /home/www/htdocs/ping/$1/index.hmtl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, решилось добавлением строчки:

```
rewrite ^/ping/images/(\d+)/i\.png$ /ping/images/$1/ last;
```